# Configure PowerPoint using interop API

Tags: api, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

I am using powerpoint interop API to open a slideshow from a new instance of PowerPoint (in this case, PowerPoint 2007).

In my app, I need to avoid the mouse changing the slide or showing up the right-click menu, so I manually configured that in PowerPoint.

What I did:

1.- For left click I went to "Animations">"Advance slide" and unchecked "On mouse click".

2.- For right click I went to "PowerPoint Options">"Advanced">"SlideShow" and unchecked "Show menu on right mouse click".

I would like to know how to do steps "1" and "2" programatically using the API, since I want my app to work in the same conditions in other computers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For number 1**, you are looking for the [SlideShowTransistion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowtransition_members.aspx) interface and in particular the [AdvanceOnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowtransition.advanceonclick.aspx) property.  It looks like you need to set it for each slide in the presentation:

```
pptSlide.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceOnClick = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

**For number 2**, I can't find anywhere this is exposed through the interop API.  The only method I can find to disable it is to modify the registry key (this would be per user install).

On my Powerpoint 2003 install it is controlled by the

```
HKEY_USERS\Unique-ID-For-User\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\PowerPoint\Options\SSRightMouse
```

reg key.